# How to use the full node?

Tags: full-node

I am new to Monero but have read some documentation and have read that it is recommended to use the full node and so I installed it to my PC. The problem is the I got no idea how to send money or receive money, like what should I do in order to start a transaction etc.

To me, that is the core factors about these services so I do not know why I have not been able to find a place where I could read some instructions about this.

Comment: Can you clarify if you have questions about how to use the command line wallet or the graphical user interface and also specify your operating system?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the full node by running the Monero GUI Wallet (however it's in Beta 2)

here's the link for windows
https://downloads.getmonero.org/gui/monero-gui-win-x64-v0.10.3.1.zip

Answer (score 0):

Full node has to run and completely update itself so you can use the wallet.
The wallet is a separate program but still dependent on the full node and its current blockchain.

There is a complete set of instructions for the command line wallet on the GetMonero site here--https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/user-guides/monero-wallet-cli